# Get string between character using regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

What should be the `Regex` expression to extract string between `<>` from the following string :

```
 "MyName"<myname@11.com>
```

How do i only extract `myname@11.com` in c# using regex ? I can extract `MyName` which is in-between `""` using the expression : `"""([^""]*)"""` but i find regex very confusing so can't seem to figure out how to extract the string in-between `<>` :(

Comment: Forget Regular Expressions. Use `(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("\"MyName\"<myname@11.com>")).Address` and let the Framework do the hard work ;)

Comment: the following string was just an example,it won't necessarily contain an email and a name , but it might always contain the special characters...Anyway,thanks @phuzi

Comment: Will still work with `new MailAddress("<myname@11.com>")` and `new MailAddress("myname@11.com")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here it is:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "<myname@11.com>";
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"<(.*?)>");

    Console.WriteLine(rx.Match(input).Groups[1].Value);
}
```

This regex contains several parts: 
`<` and `>` symbols say that my text is between them 
`()` - is group declaration, what we see here `Groups[1]`. Zero group would contain whole line with `<>` symbols 
`.*` - any character with any length 
`?` - non-greedy search, so if you have there `"<myname@11.com><asdasd>"` it will still return correct value and not get result `myname@11.com><asdasd`

[Example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3c%28.*%3f%29%3e&i=%22MyName%22%3cmyname%4011.com%3e)

Comment: How did u figure this out ? i find regex very very confusing..can u please explain the expression so that i can use it in future without any problem ?

Comment: I find this site very helpful... http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

Comment: and wait.....why is the `input` string `<myname@11.com>`..Instead,that should be `"MyName"<myname@11.com>`..maybe u got me wrong ?

Comment: @zack (.*?) is a non-greedy wildcard capture. It will start after < and end before the next >. It will work for your example, too.

Comment: @zack I added an example to Alexey's answer.

Comment: Not sure if it's a problem to @zackraiyan, but the regex is insufficient if the part between double quotes can also contain `<` and `>`. E.g. `"<MyName>"<myname@11.com>` is matched incorrectly.

Comment: no....there won't be `<MyName>` , `MyName` would always be between quotes like `"MyName"`

Comment: @zackraiyan so `input = @"""MyName""<myname@11.com>";` ? still works for this string

Comment: Just curious : Does Regex expression differ in c# and vb.net ?

Comment: @zackraiyan AFAIK no

Comment: i currently have a demo project running in vb.net(i know my post has a tag of `c#` and even my main proj is in `c#` but this test proj is in vb.net).I am currently trying to apply ur solution but seems like it doesn't work : https://pastebin.com/gwxgHc1i

Comment: @zackraiyan can you provide code?

Comment: i gave u link of `pastebin` , it has my code

Comment: @zackraiyan sorry, from mobilephone didn't get about link, it looks not really.. convenient, please check this url https://dotnetfiddle.net/pfFMwA

Comment: anyway,the code works fine :)

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<=<).*(?=>)
```

positive lookbehind `(?<=<)` a `<` has to be infront

positive ahead`(?=>)` a `>` has to be an the end

`.*` any character could be in the middle

https://regex101.com/r/4ExLWp/1

Answer (score 2):

Why use a Regular Expression at all. Just use `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress`...

```
var mailAddress = new MailAddress(@"""MyName""<myname@11.com>");
Console.WriteLine(mailAddress.Address); // prints myname@11.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use this regex :

```
<(.*)>
```

you can try it online there :
https://regex101.com/

if it's everytime an email in the <> tag you can replace .* by an email regex like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+
```

Comment: i know about that site but how did u figure out the expression ? IS there any general rule ?

Comment: you can learn regex with some site like :
https://regexone.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `^(?<namegroup>.*)(?<emailGroup>\<.*?\>)$`

You can test any regex here on https://regex101.com/.
It's pretty good described there what exactly means what and pretty highlighted.

The groups I used are just to make it clear, there's no need to name them.
This is the expression without named groups:

```
^(.*)(\<.*?\>)$
```

In both regex's, you can get the "MyName" in group 1 and the email with <> in group 2. If you need the email without the <>, just move them out of the brackets

Comment: i wonder how can i get so many `Regex` answer so fast :) ?

Comment: Regex is a mighty tool if used properly but can also cause a lot of mess because most expressions are hard to understand. It's fun creating them :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    string input = @"""MyName""<myname@11.com>";
    string regex = "<[^>]*>";

    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(input, regex).Value);
}
```

The "<" is looking for that character, the "[^>]" is looking for anything that is not ">", the "*" looks for one or more of the previous which is "[^>]", and the ">" looks for that character. It is looking for "<" then one or more of anything that is not ">" then ">". I use [this website](https://regexr.com/) to learn regex and test things out. It shows you live what is captured and has a cheat sheet that also describes your regex.